# On App Relaunch How to call function sign(didSignInFor) of google sign in for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The function

`func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)`

is called after successfully signing in but when relaunching the app the function also needs to be called to get the users data. I don't know how handle an App relaunch.

I tried `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently`, but it is not working. The function `sign` is not getting called. How can I get the current user's data after relaunching the app?

Within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function I tried:

```
if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.hasAuthInKeychain()) == true {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    }
}
```

but im not getting the current user, and the function `didSignIn` is not getting called. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)` every time you relaunch the app.

You can simple save user detail once user successfully sign in with google and you can get `accessToken` with

```
let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken
```

and you can save it locally like in `UserDefault` and next time when user relaunch the app you can easily identified by accessing that `accessToken` locally.

And with `func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)` user parameter will have the user data when user tried to login. And can save that data locally as well.

And with logout you can simple remove the data locally so that when user relaunch the app he need to login again.

**Update:**

You can access user info with `profile` property of `user`. check below example

```
print(user.profile.email)
print(user.profile.name)
print(user.profile.familyName)
print(user.profile.givenName)
print(user.profile.hasImage)
```

Comment: thanks! I understand.. but then how to get the data once I retrieve the accesToken?

Comment: User info will be there with accessToken

Comment: but how do I get the info with the accessToken? @Dharmesh

Comment: but what is the use of the accessToken, sorry I don't understand, lets supposed I get the accessToken from user defaults, then what? how can I use it ? what is the purpose and how does it work? @Dharmesh

Comment: accessToken is basically for server. lets suppose you are sending login data to server you can send this token to server and server can get user information from google.